# Apache Camel Olingo4 read Data

Tags: apache-camel, odata, olingo

I'm facing some issue by reading nested data from an odata api. I'm using Olingo4 with camel 3.20.5.

I first have to filter a collection by key and then want to return a collection from this value. The key-filter is a string, containing a space. In the browser, everything works fine.
The url looks like this:

`http://baseOdataUrl/Customer('23 abc')/Orders`

where `Customer` is a collection and `Orders` is a `NavigationProperty` with type `Collection(NAV.Orders)`.

My camel route looks like this:

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.to("olingo4://read/Customer('23 abc')/Orders?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

which is failing with error: Illegal character in url

which indicates, it's not being parsed properly at the position of the space.

I tried several approaches:

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.to("olingo4://read/Customer('23%20abc')/Orders?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

which is not returning anything.

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.to("olingo4://read/Customer/Orders?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

failing: Orders is not allowed after a collection

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.setHeader("CamelOlingo4.keyPredicate", constant("23 abc"))
.to("olingo4://read/Customer/Orders?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

which is trying to filter the Orders, I think, because it's generating url like `/Customer/Orders(23 abc)`

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.setHeader("CamelOlingo4.keyPredicate", constant("'23 abc'")) // failing like before
.setHeader("CamelOlingo4.keyPredicate", constant("'23%20abc'")) // failing like before
.to("olingo4://read/Customer/Orders?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

I also tried to urlencode the `'` and double them. Still no luck.

This working, but not what I want, because it's just returning the customers:

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.setHeader("CamelOlingo4.$filter", constant("Name eq '23 abc'"))
.to("olingo4://read/Customer?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

This is generating an empty node `Orders` inside of Customers:

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.setHeader("CamelOlingo4.$filter", constant("Name eq '23 abc'"))
.setHeader("CamelOlingo4.$expand", constant("Orders"))
.to("olingo4://read/Customer?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

If I'm executing this in the browser, it's producing the same wrong result.

So I just want to execute the working browser query from the beginning in camel and get the same correct results there.

The httpClientBuilder is only being used for the NTLM authentication.

I think, it's an easy query, which is running perfectly fine in browser, so there must be an issue with my syntax in camel.

**UPDATE**

It's working now, with the following route:

```
from("timer:mytimer?period=1000")
.setHeader("CamelOlingo4.resourcePath", constant("Customer('23%20abc')/Orders"))
.to("olingo4:read?serviceUri=baseOdataUrl&httpAsyncClientBuilder=#myHttpClientBuilder");
```

Probably there were some issues during encoding. But now, I'm getting the following error:

```
ODataException: "Unsupported resource type: navigationProperty"
```

thrown here https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/3a550051b36e2f76d39c18b927e48158de007fd0/components/camel-olingo4/camel-olingo4-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/olingo4/api/impl/Olingo4AppImpl.java#L590

Is it not possible, to process the data?

Many thanks in advance, and let me know, if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up, using the `http` component of camel, put all the attributes like `$filter` and `$orderby` in the url and unmarshal the result as json with the `Jackson` library into my POJO.

Thanks anyway for reading